# Safe label-based selection in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How can I safely select rows in pandas by a list of labels?
I want to get and `Error` when list contains **any non-existing label**.

**Method `loc` doesn't raise a KeyError if at least 1 of the labels for which you ask is in the index.** But this is not sufficient.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list('abcde'), data={'A': np.arange(5) + 10})

df
    A
a  10
b  11
c  12
d  13
e  14

# here I would like to get an Error as 'xx' and 'yy' are not in the index
df.loc[['b', 'xx', 'yy']] 

       A
b   11.0
xx   NaN
yy   NaN
```

Do pandas provide such a method that would raise a KeyError instead of returning me a bunch of **NaNs** for non-existing labels?

Comment: @maxU this is the selction of columns that you suggest. `df[['b']]` will also raise a `KeyError`

Comment: yep, you are right, sorry!

Comment: I don't know whether it's sufficient for you, but you can check it beforehand: `len(pd.Index(['b', 'xx', 'yy']).difference(df.index))` should be `0`

Comment: Yes, but It's a pity if we have to do checking ourselves. It's a bit cumbersome. Maybe somebody offers something else.

Comment: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61291741/passing-list-likes-to-loc-or-with-any-missing-labels-is-no-longer-supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bit a hack, but one can do this like this:

```
def my_loc(df, idx):
    assert len(df.index[df.index.isin(idx)]) == len(idx), 'KeyError:the labels [{}] are not in the [index]'.format(idx)
    return df.loc[idx]

In [243]: my_loc(df, idx)
...
skipped
...
AssertionError: KeyError:the labels [['b', 'xx', 'yy']] are not in the [index]

In [245]: my_loc(df, ['a','c','e'])
Out[245]:
    A
a  10
c  12
e  14
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you get `NaN` because `loc` or `ix` return same output as `reindex`. See [reindex versus ix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#reindex-versus-ix-gotchas).

Solution for 'safe' selecting from open [issue 10695](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10695):

```
list_of_values = ['b', 'xx', 'yy']
print (df.ix[df.reset_index()['index'].isin(list_of_values).values])
    A
b  11
```

One solution for return error if values are not in `index` is use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop.html):

```
df.drop(list_of_values)
print (df.loc[list_of_values])
```

> ValueError: labels ['xx' 'yy'] not contained in axis

Answer (score 1):

`.loc[]` won't let you set values if the index in the list is not part of the initial `df`

so you could do something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a','b','c','d', 'e'], data={'A':range(5)})
index_list = ['a', 'b']
df.loc[index_list] = df.loc[index_list]
df.loc[index_list]
Out[288]: 
   A
a  0
b  1
```

now let's test for a dummy index:

```
index_list = ['aa', 'b']
df.loc[index_list] = df.loc[index_list]
```

you will get this error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
      File "<ipython-input-289-d6aac5dac03d>", line 2, in <module>
        df.loc[index_list] = df.loc[index_list]
      File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 139, in __setitem__
        indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
      File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 126, in _get_setitem_indexer
        return self._convert_to_indexer(key, is_setter=True)
      File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1229, in _convert_to_indexer
        raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
    KeyError: "['aa'] not in index"
```

Comment: I tested with `timeit` this approach. And it is a bit slower than checking that `len(df.index[df.index.isin(idx)]) == len(idx)`. *~1 sec vs ~0.5 sec* for 100 repeats with `df` with 50000 rows and for `idx` with 50000 elements

Comment: yes this hack is not performance oriented but was more an answer on how to return `ValueError` with `loc[]`