# Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to create a modified dataframe with the specified columns.
I tried the following but throws the error "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported"

```
# columns to keep
filtered_columns = ['text', 'agreeCount', 'disagreeCount', 'id', 'user.firstName', 'user.lastName', 'user.gender', 'user.id']
tips_filtered = tips_df.loc[:, filtered_columns]

# display tips
tips_filtered
```

Thank you

Comment: Check for typos or leading/trailing spaces in the `df.columns` too , if necessary you can `str.strip()` them off. Some/any of the columns is not present in the actual dataframe

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It looks like Pandas has deprecated this method of indexing. According to their [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated):

> This behavior is deprecated and will show a warning message pointing
> to this section. The recommended alternative is to use .reindex()

Using the new [recommended method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#reindexing), you can filter your columns using:

`tips_filtered = tips_df.reindex(columns = filtered_columns)`.

NB: To reindex rows, you would use `reindex(index = ...)` (More information [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html#pandas.Series.reindex)).

Answer (score 16):

Some of the columns in the list are not included in the dataframe , if you do want do that , let us try `reindex`

```
tips_filtered = tips_df.reindex(columns=filtered_columns)
```

Comment: It worked. All the columns are there in the data frame. Still, why was it throwing that error?

Comment: @swasthiknayak let us do , `set(filtered_columns).difference(set(df.columns.tolist()))`, and check the rest;t

Answer (score 15):

**I encountered the same error with missing row index labels rather than columns**.
For example, I would have a dataset of products with the following ids: ['a','b','c','d']. I store those products in a dataframe with indices `['a','b','c','d']`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(['product a','product b','product c', 'product d'],index=['a','b','c','d'])
```

Now let's assume I have an updated product index:
`row_indices=['b','c','d','e']` in which 'e' corresponds to a new product: 'product e'. Note that 'e' was not present in my original index `['a','b','c','d']`.

If I try to pass this updated index to my df dataframe: `df.loc[row_indices,:]`,

I'll get this nasty error message:

> KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index(['e'], dtype='object').

To avoid this error I need to do intersection of my updated index with the original index:

```
df.loc[df.index.intersection(row_indices),:]
```

[this is in line with recommendation of what pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike)

Comment: I encountered this problem today, and you save my life. Thank you so much @Kuffner

Comment: Thank you for this - I needed a quick method for reindexing stock price data such that there are ffilled prices on non-market days (just reindex with ffill and a date range, no prob), but I needed to also indicate which were the market days - I saved my original index, and then went to use .loc with the original index to set MarketDay=True - none of the normal methods worked -  this method was the only thing that worked.  So I thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This error pops up if indexing on something which is not present - reset_index() worked for me as I was indexing on a subset of the actual dataframe with actual indices, in this case the column may not be present in the dataframe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to create new columns along with existing ones :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]], columns=["a","b","c"])
def foobar(a,b):
  return a,b
df[["c","d"]] = df.apply(lambda row: foobar(row["a"], row["b"]), axis=1)
```

The solution was to add `result_type="expand"` as an argument of `apply()` :

```
df[["c","d"]] = df.apply(lambda row: foobar(row["a"], row["b"]), axis=1, result_type="expand")
```