# 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda, spyder

Here's a rough draft of my code

```
file_n = 'Customers_1';
ext =  '.xlsx';
filename = file_n+ext;
df = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name="Sheet1");
df.rename(columns={'CustomerId':'crn','LastVisitedDateTime':'time'}, inplace=True);

df_temp= df.groupby(df.PageName).crn.count();


df_t=df.loc[df.PageName == 'Login',['crn','PageName','time']];
```

Getting the following error-:

'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike%27)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61291741/14066512

Comment: ... so are you passing missing labels? What is your question?